# 301 Redirect all page and post urls from .html to /

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a current site which got all URLS end with .html.

I created a new site and the URLS are pretty much the same but without .html.

I've been trying codes found here in my .htaccess file and most seem to cause Internal Server Error.

```
http://example.com/page1.html to http://example.com/page1/
http://example.com/page1/page2.html to http://example.com/page1/page2/
```

My current htacces file code is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Simple 301 Redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) plugin and try to setting like image below. Just tested on my live site and it's running exactly what you want.

Remember you checked `Use wildcards?` checkbox too.

[image]